# Visualforce datepicker not working

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap

I am using bootstrap accordion to develop my page along with visualforce. However my datepicker is not working for any inputfield. property is of type Property__c which is my custom object and has dob__c field of type date. Whenever i click on the date inputbox i am getting the this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentStyle' of null
>       at Object.getStyle (main.js:410)
>       at Object.setStyle (main.js:409)
>       at iframeShim.setStyle (main.js:1353)
>       at DatePicker.hide (main.js:661)
>       at HTMLDocument.DatePicker.closeHandler (main.js:649)

and

> main.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener'
>   of null

my code:

```
<apex:page>
<apex:form>
<body>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-
parent="#accordion" href="#basic_details">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        Basic Details
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="basic_details" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2" >
                                <apex:outputLabel for="name" 
 styleClass="labelClass">name</apex:outputLabel>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2" >
                                <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control 
 input-sm ;" style="font-weight: 100;"  value="{!property.Name__c}" id="name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2"  >
                                <apex:outputLabel for="gender" styleClass="labelClass">Gender</apex:outputLabel>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control input-sm ;" style="font-weight: 100;"  value="{!property.gender__c}" id="gender" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2"  >
                                <apex:outputLabel for="dob" styleClass="labelClass">Branch Name</apex:outputLabel>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control input-sm ;" style="font-weight: 100;"  value="{!property.dob__c}" id="dob" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
</apex:form>
</body>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.LAFiles, 'jquery.min.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.LAFiles, 'bootstrap.min.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.LAFiles, 'jquery-1.10.2.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.LAFiles, 'jquery-ui.js')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.LAFiles, 'bootstrap.min.css')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.LAFiles, 'jquery-ui.css')}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Your property.dob__c is bound to an outputField, just FYI.

Comment: Changed that @SantanuHalder